# Movie/video game about fighter pilots whose custom was to pretend that dead colleagues never existed

Tags: story-identification

I have a vague recollection of a movie (or a video game with live-action cutscenes) about a group of pilots fighting a war in space against aliens.

They were based on what was essentially a futuristic aircraft carrier in space, where most of the scenes were filmed. Whenever somebody died in combat, it was their custom to remove all of their things, and every trace of them from the ship, and to never speak about them again so that it was as if they had never existed.

It was English language and I'm pretty certain that the cast were Americans, and that it was live action rather than CGI or anime.

I'm not 100% certain but it could be the *Wing Commander* movie.

Comment: By the by, is there anything Valorum can do to improve his answer for acceptance?

Answer (score 17):

This is indeed the *[Wing Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wing_Commander_(film))* (1999) film. After someone dies, you basically act like they were never there.

> MARSHALL: No, he just made the fatal error of mistaking our wing
> commander for your average grease monkey. Listen, all I did was sit in
> Commander Chen's fighter.
>
> BLAIR: Lieutenant Commander Chen? Bossman?
>
> HUNTER: You're talking about a bloke that never existed.
>
> BLAIR: I'm pretty sure he did.
>
> HUNTER: He...never...existed. Now change the subject quickly, pal
> before I change it for you.

Comment: If your plan is to watch Wing Commander with friends, may I suggest that avoid the drinking game where you do a shot every time someone overacts.

Comment: I'd suggest just avoiding the movie. It was terrible.

Comment: @AaarghZombies - I liked it. But then I've seen [Starcrash](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079946/), so *everything* looks good by comparison.

Comment: @AaarghZombies It wasn't that bad. A solid B movie.

Comment: It strayed significantly from the source material.

Comment: @AaarghZombies Then I hope you never have the misfortune to meet *Doom*. :)

Comment: Watched it when I was very gullible (more than now). The ending was... very underwhelming.